# How to detect resize in NSView in Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: cocoa, xamarin.mac

What is the correct way to detect when a NSView is resized ?.
I do not see any resize event available on the view or any delegate for the view.

I have added this hack, where I use the drawRect to detect the change in size, but I'm sure there must be a more correct way to do this.

```
    CGRect m_resizeRect = CGRect.Empty;
    public override void DrawRect(CGRect dirtyRect)
    {
        base.DrawRect(dirtyRect);
        if (this.InLiveResize) {
            if (m_resizeRect.Size != this.Bounds.Size) {
                m_resizeRect = this.Bounds;
                this.OnResize();
            }
        }
    }
    public override void ViewWillStartLiveResize()
    {
        m_resizeRect = this.Bounds;
        base.ViewWillStartLiveResize();
    }
    public override void ViewDidEndLiveResize()
    {
        m_resizeRect = CGRect.Empty;
        base.ViewDidEndLiveResize();
    }
    protected void OnResize() {
        Console.WriteLine("OnResize " + this.Bounds.ToString() );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the resize notifications.

#### Add observer to default notification center:

```
NSObject NSWindowDidResizeNotificationObject;
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    NSWindowDidResizeNotificationObject = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (new NSString ("NSWindowDidResizeNotification"), ResizeObserver, null);
}
```

#### NSNotification Action:

```
public void ResizeObserver (NSNotification notify)
{
    var r = this.View.Frame;
    Console.WriteLine ("{0}:{1}:{1}", notify.Name, r.Height, r.Width);
}
```

#### Remove observer (and release memory):

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver (NSWindowDidResizeNotificationObject);
```

#### Sample Output:

```
NSWindowDidResizeNotification:740:740
NSWindowDidResizeNotification:715:715
NSWindowDidResizeNotification:681:681
NSWindowDidResizeNotification:642:642
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the setFrameSize method and do your own stuff every time the frame is updated.

```
class MyView: NSView {
    ...
    override func setFrameSize(newSize: NSSize) {
        super.setFrameSize(newSize)
        Swift.print("new size is \(frame)")
    }
    ...
}
```

The accepted answer only seems to respond to window size changes and not e.g. when the split-bar of a splitview causes the resize.

Answer (score 2):

See the NSView [`postsBoundsChangedNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/postsBoundsChangedNotifications) and [`postFrameChangedNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/postsFrameChangedNotifications) properties. You can set those and register for those notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *NSViewController.viewDidLayout()* overriden method:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    ...
    override func viewDidLayout() {
        Swift.print("view has been resize to \(self.view.frame)")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: NSView doesn't have a viewDidLayout() method?

Comment: Sorry my mistake it's NSViewController I just fixed it.

Comment: @Adrian I edited my answer, can you please reconsider your downvote?

Comment: This no longer pertains to the question. Respectfully suggest deleting the answer?

Comment: Why? this is the way I handle resize in my application.

Comment: @MartinDelille It doesn't work if `layout` method wasn't called after user updated the frame size. Observing `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` is the recommended way.